# Is it correct to use window.location.reload with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When you open [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org/), under "Declarative" header, there is a sentence: **React will efficiently update and render just the right components when your data changes.**

For a couple of my apps, I'm using the following structure: 
App
|    AppContainer(all the app logic, protected before login)
|    Login(Login form)

This structure works well if you return 2 different components inside App's `render`, according to the user's credentials.

```
render(){
   if(isUserLoggedIn()){
       return <AppContainer />;
   }

   return <Login />;
}
```

Inside the `Login` component, I'm refreshing the page with `window.location.reload` so the App's `render` will be triggered, and I'll get the `AppContainer` component.

*But it feels a little like jQuery + Angular.* Is there a better (more React) way to trigger render function, or is this how things should be?

Comment: if there is a state update happening in `App` component, the render will be called

Comment: yes , you can do so , just maintain a ```isAuthenticated``` state in your **redux**, and that way conditionally , you render will be triggered aagain

Comment: Probably  [`react-router-dom`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) fits to what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better(more React) way to trigger render function...

The usual way is to have state, in this case at minimum a boolean for whether the user is logged in, and update that state when the user logs in successfully or logs out. Updating state triggers rendering.

In your case, since you're using Redux, you'd probably have your state there.

I don't use Redux (yet?), this is vaguely what it would look like without, roughly (if you're using a class component as you seem to be):

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loggedIn: /*...initial value, perhaps from web storage or cookie...*/;
        };
        this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this);
        this.onLogout = this.onLogout.bind(this);
    }

    onLogin() {
        // ...probably stuff here, then:
        this.setState({loggedIn: true});
    }

    onLogout() {
        // ...probably stuff here, then:
        this.setState({loggedIn: false});
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.logedIn) {
            return <AppComponent onLogout={this.onLogout}/>;
        }
        return <Login onLogin={this.onLogin}/>;
    }
}
```

or with hooks:

```
const App = () => {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(/*...initial value, perhaps from web storage or cookie...*/);

    const onLogin = useCallback(() => {
        // ...probably stuff here, then:
        setLoggedIn(true);
    }, [loggedIn]);

    const onLogout = useCallback(() => {
        // ...probably stuff here, then:
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }, [loggedIn]);

    if (this.state.logedIn) {
        return <AppComponent onLogout={onLogout}/>;
    }
    return <Login onLogin={onLogin}/>;
}
```

(again, roughly)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update the component state, then you can pass an observable and listen for changes or use some state management library.

Here is one possible solution:

1. Create observable class

```
declare type IObserverHandler = (event: any) => void;
export class Observable {
    private observers: IObserverHandler[] = [];

    public subscribe(observer: IObserverHandler) {
        if (!this.observers.includes(observer)) {
            this.observers.push(observer);
        }
    }
    public unsubscribe(observer: IObserverHandler) {
        this.observers = this.observers.filter(o => o !== observer);
    }
    public publish(event: any) {
        for (const observer of this.observers) {
            observer(event);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Create Login class that will publish events on actions such as login or logout

```
class Login extends Observable {

    public login() {
        this.publish({ value: true });
    }

    public logout() {
        this.publish({ value: false });
    }
}
```

3. In component subscribe to observer and update component state using event value

```
export abstract class Component extends React.Component<any, any> {
    private observer: IObserverHandler;
    private observable: Login;

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.observable = this.props.observable;
        this.state = { isAuthenticated: false }

        this.observer = (event) => {
            this.setState({ isAuthenticated: event.value })
        }
        this.observable.subscribe(this.observer);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.observable.unsubscribe(this.observer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useNavigate` and navigate to the same url you are on. For example, instead of `window.location.reload()`, you can say `navigate("/...your current url....")`

`window.location.reload()` is not the best option everytime. It works on localhost, but for example on when you deploy it to the internet by using services such as "Netlify", it can can cause "not found url" error

Creating some extra state and tracking them for re-rendering your page might unnecessarily complicate your code.